# Laravel passport returns error on PassportUserProvider null given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-passport

While using the 'auth:api' middleware, using a freshly generated token, my request returns a typeError in the laravel code.

```
Argument 1 passed to Laravel\\Passport\\PassportUserProvider::__construct() 
must implement interface Illuminate\\Contracts\\Auth\\UserProvider, null given
```

I tried some debugging and managed to find the causing code but i dont understand how to fix this.

It is in this piece of code from the laravel PassportServiceProvider.php file

```
return new RequestGuard(function ($request) use ($config) {
        return (new TokenGuard(
            $this->app->make(ResourceServer::class),
            new PassportUserProvider(Auth::createUserProvider($config['provider']), $config['provider']),
            $this->app->make(TokenRepository::class),
            $this->app->make(ClientRepository::class),
            $this->app->make('encrypter')
        ))->user($request);
    }, $this->app['request']);
```

The part that causes the error is the line:

```
new PassportUserProvider(Auth::createUserProvider($config['provider']), $config['provider'])
```

The `$config['provider']` is equal to 'clients', aparently the method will only take 'users' as valid input but i dont understand where this 'clients' is comming from.

```
return [

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
],

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],
],

'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: show your `auth.php` config

Comment: added it to the original question.

Comment: Does the `App\Models\User::class` exists?

Comment: about "clients" - if you want to add new provider - add it to `providers` array with key `client` and specify Client model - like in "users"

Comment: But i don;t want a new provider, i just want to use passport as the API authenticator and the user that is used there should be the client (so the model User)

Comment: If anyone else is stuck here, I solved it by making the api provider "user" instead of users and then I defined a user provider under providers with the same data as providers->users.